# How to serialize GUID as native UUID in BSON using JSON.NET

Tags: .net, json.net, bson

JSON.NET does not seem to want to serialize GUIDs as native BSON UUIDs, and instead is outputting GUIDs as strings.

I have tested generating BSON from both a `JObject` (verifying prior to serialization that the `JValue.Type == JTokenType.Guid`), and an anonymous type (`new { myUuid = new Guid() }`) with no luck in either case.

How can I force JSON.NET to serialize GUIDs as native BSON UUIDs (a 16 byte binary value; subtype=0x04)?

*Sample Code:*

```
var source = new
{
    myInteger = 123L,
    myFloat = 10.0f,
    myString = "hello",
    myUuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
    myBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
    myDatetime = DateTime.UtcNow,
};

MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream();
BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(buffer);
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(writer, source);
byte[] myBson = buffer.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from this implementation of `WriteValue` on the `BsonWriter` (in version 4.5.0.0):

```
public override void WriteValue(Guid value)
{
  base.WriteValue(value);
  this.AddToken((BsonToken) new BsonString((object) value.ToString(), true));
}
```

Note the second line, it's writing the [`Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx) as a string, which is why you're seeing the results that you are.

Using the following example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var source = new
    {
        myUuid = Guid.NewGuid(),
    };

    using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new BsonWriter(buffer))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, source);
        byte[] myBson = buffer.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I'd expect the bytes starting at index 12 to be (as per the [spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)):

- `\0x05` to indicate the type of binary
- A four byte int (with a value of 16, the length of the binary data)
- `\0x04` to indicate a subtype of [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)
- 16 bytes to represent the content of the `Guid`/UUID.

This is obviously a bug, and [I've filed a bug for this in the issue tracker for Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/23715).